# How to do SAP RFC connection with PHP in Xampp localhost

Tags: php, saprfc

I tried to setup SAPRFC in Windows system xampp.

- Copy the `php-saprfc.dll` file into php/ext  folder..
- Add the `extension=php_saprfc.dll` line in `php.ini` file
- Then where can I find the `librfc32.dll` file in SAP?

I installed SAP also...

How to setup PHP with SAP?

Any solution please tell...

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? Is there anything that's not working as you expect it to?

Comment: Yes how to connect SAp With PHP in XAmpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download dll and php_saprfc file from this link

Visit http://liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net/project/saprfcsapnwrfc/saprfc-1.4.1.zip

Answer (score 2):

First you need to take sure that saprfc is installed successfully.
Check phpinfo if the extension is listed (or on the CLI: php -m)
Make sure that you have the correct *.dll for SAP! (check my 2nd link)

There is a newer version (SAP NW RFC) here, with a lot of informations
https://github.com/piersharding/php-sapnwrfc

I also added some windows builds here some time ago, with the documentation to install: https://github.com/piersharding/php-sapnwrfc/tree/master/builds

Comment: sry saprfc is not listed in php info page

Comment: If u have your informations, please accept the answer